# Precise timing with DeepSleep on an ESP8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp32

I have a ESP8266, which I use to log weather data over MQTT. Because I want to save some power, I decided to use DeepSleep. Since I want to log the data, it would be good if I could send new entries every minute.

This used to work with my old sketch, where I had all data acquisition tasks in the *loop* section, and where I kept the connection to WiFi and the MQTT-Server open.

But this does not work with DeepSleep. I need to reconnect after every wake-up and after every wake-up, the ESP8266 basically reboots.

Because this does not take exactly the same time on every wake-up, I wanted to know if there is a way to let the ESP8266 log on exactly the same timestamps and go to DeepSleep in between?

This is a code sample of the DeepSleep algorithm:

```
String JSON = "{\"sensor\": \"Outdoor Sensor\", \"data\":[" + String(temp) + "," + String(hum) + "," + String(brightness) + "]}";
client.publish(topic, JSON.c_str(), true); //publish data as JSON to MQTT
delay(10); //somehow if this is not added, the data does not get logged.
Serial.println("Going into deep sleep for 60 seconds");
ESP.deepSleep(56e6); // because of microseconds - processing data takes about 4sec, but this is very unprecise
```

This is from PhpMyAdmin, in order to better visualize the problem:

[image]

If it can not be done with an ESP8266, might a ESP32 help?

Comment: look into the NTC library; it can fetch the GMT time for you, and you can use that as a log datetime. it will take longer to log each thing, since it's more work. you could use an RTC as well. you could also use 2-3 8266s + ESPNOW to avoid that boot delay; espnow slaves can send off a message in 200ms from cold boot. the other esp catches the broadcast and sends it over serial to the third ESP, which is connect to Wifi and does all the network action. seems complex, but once you have an ESPNOW "brouter" setup, you can add lots of other nodes without a lot of additional effort.

Comment: Well, I have thought about ESPNOW, but that would make my power saving effort redundant, since I would need a second ESP8266 running all time.

Comment: Can I use the NTC library, to wake the ESP8266 from DeepSleep?

Comment: no, but you can find the real time with it once you wake.

Comment: To use an external RTC: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/91503/how-do-i-wake-the-esp8266-from-deep-sleep-on-a-specific-date-and-time/91504#91504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is suggested [using an external RTC](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/91503/how-do-i-wake-the-esp8266-from-deep-sleep-on-a-specific-date-and-time/91504#91504) if time tracking is of importance. Using the internal RTC, improving meassurement of time passage during sleep apparently includes guessing at the sleeping chip's temperature:

Time keeping on the ESP8266 is technically quite challenging. Despite being named RTC, while it does keep a counter ticking while the module is sleeping, the accuracy with which it does so is highly dependent on the temperature of the chip. Said temperature changes significantly once in deep sleep mode, calibration performed while the chip was active becomes useless mere moments after the chip has gone to sleep.

http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/65530/ddg#65532

Where high accuracy isn't required I would suggest to take a few samples and calculate the average interval error.

**example with 5 minutes intervals:**

[excel calculation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iPnD.png)

```
int32_t deep_sleep_time_compensation = -145000000; // chip temperature dependant deep sleep duration error compensation in μs
ESP.deepSleep(300e6-micros()-deep_sleep_time_compensation); // because of microseconds; micros() is reset on wake-up
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a (not perfect) workaround.
If I do

```
Serial.println("Going into deep sleep so that next data gets posted in a minute");
Serial.println(60e6-micros());
ESP.deepSleep(60e6-micros()); // because of microseconds; micros() is reset on wake-up
```

then I get slightly better results. I do however not understand, why it is not working perfectly.

In my opinion it should, since I count the time the whole boot process + code run took and then substract that time from the time the ESP8266 is in DeepSleep.